# Writing Dynamic JSP Using Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, printwriter

I store my HTML pages in the database, and I use `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter ();` to show them. I would like to do the same with my JSP pages it is possible to do this using `JspWriter`

Example: I have this page in my database, I load this page and would like the code to be processed dynamically (inside servlet).

```
<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <%
            // Get current time
            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

            String am_pm;
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            if (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0) {
                am_pm = "AM";
            } else {
                am_pm = "PM";
            }
            String CT = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + am_pm;
            out.println("Current Time is: " + CT + "\n");
        %>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. The servlet writes HTML (in this case) to the response, and your standard client (web browsers) will understand that.

A JSP, however, is a dynamic page and contains code that the container has to compile and run in order to produce the output for the HTTP response. Writing the content of the JSP to the response would (roughly speaking) send Java code to the client.

If you need dynamic content at that level, perhaps you should look into a custom tag library. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/taglib/quickstart.html)